# I am making a keyboard for android to send stickers from whatsapp but instead of stickers images are being sent. I used InputConnectionCompat.commit

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-keypad

I used  `InputConnectionCompat.commitContent` to send the content but instead of sending sticker, WhatsApp is sending images. The same code works in the telegram. Telegram sends the same image as stickers but the same is not happening in whatsapp.

here is the full code

```
package com.shyptsolution.whatsappspammer;



import android.app.AppOpsManager;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputBinding;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RawRes;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.core.view.inputmethod.EditorInfoCompat;
import androidx.core.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionCompat;
import androidx.core.view.inputmethod.InputContentInfoCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class ImageKeyboard extends InputMethodService {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageKeyboard";
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.commitcontent.ime.inputcontent";
    private static final String MIME_TYPE_GIF = "image/gif";
    private static final String MIME_TYPE_PNG = "image/png";
    private static final String MIME_TYPE_WEBP = "image/webp";

    private File mPngFile;
    private File mGifFile;
    private File mWebpFile;
    private Button mGifButton;
    private Button mPngButton;
    private Button mWebpButton;

    private boolean isCommitContentSupported(
            @Nullable EditorInfo editorInfo, @NonNull String mimeType) {
        if (editorInfo == null) {
            return false;
        }

        final InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!validatePackageName(editorInfo)) {
            return false;
        }

        final String[] supportedMimeTypes = EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo);
        for (String supportedMimeType : supportedMimeTypes) {
            if (ClipDescription.compareMimeTypes(mimeType, supportedMimeType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void doCommitContent(@NonNull String description, @NonNull String mimeType,
                                 @NonNull File file) {
        final EditorInfo editorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();

        // Validate packageName again just in case.
        if (!validatePackageName(editorInfo)) {
            return;
        }

        final Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, file);

        final int flag;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
            flag = InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
        } else {

            flag = 0;
            try {
                // TODO: Use revokeUriPermission to revoke as needed.
                grantUriPermission(
                        editorInfo.packageName, contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "grantUriPermission failed packageName=" + editorInfo.packageName
                        + " contentUri=" + contentUri, e);
            }
        }

        final InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfoCompat = new InputContentInfoCompat(
                contentUri,
                new ClipDescription(description, new String[]{mimeType}),
                null /* linkUrl */);
        InputConnectionCompat.commitContent(
                getCurrentInputConnection(), getCurrentInputEditorInfo(), inputContentInfoCompat,
                flag, null);
    }

    private boolean validatePackageName(@Nullable EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        if (editorInfo == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = editorInfo.packageName;
        if (packageName == null) {
            return false;
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }

        final InputBinding inputBinding = getCurrentInputBinding();
        if (inputBinding == null) {

            Log.e(TAG, "inputBinding should not be null here. "
                    + "You are likely to be hitting b.android.com/225029");
            return false;
        }
        final int packageUid = inputBinding.getUid();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            final AppOpsManager appOpsManager =
                    (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            try {
                appOpsManager.checkPackage(packageUid, packageName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final String possiblePackageNames[] = packageManager.getPackagesForUid(packageUid);
        for (final String possiblePackageName : possiblePackageNames) {
            if (packageName.equals(possiblePackageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // TODO: Avoid file I/O in the main thread.
        final File imagesDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
        imagesDir.mkdirs();
        mGifFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.animated_gif, imagesDir, "image.gif");
        mPngFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.icon, imagesDir, "image.png");
        mWebpFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.animated_webp, imagesDir, "image.webp");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        mGifButton = new Button(this);
        mGifButton.setText("Insert GIF");
        mGifButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent("A waving flag", MIME_TYPE_GIF, mGifFile);
            }
        });

        mPngButton = new Button(this);
        mPngButton.setText("Insert PNG");
        mPngButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent("A droid logo", MIME_TYPE_PNG, mPngFile);
            }
        });

        mWebpButton = new Button(this);
        mWebpButton.setText("Insert WebP");
        mWebpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent(
                        "Android N recovery animation", MIME_TYPE_WEBP, mWebpFile);
            }
        });

        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(mGifButton);
        layout.addView(mPngButton);
        layout.addView(mWebpButton);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {
        mGifButton.setEnabled(mGifFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_GIF));
        mPngButton.setEnabled(mPngFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_PNG));
        mWebpButton.setEnabled(mWebpFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_WEBP));
    }

    private static File getFileForResource(
            @NonNull Context context, @RawRes int res, @NonNull File outputDir,
            @NonNull String filename) {
        final File outputFile = new File(outputDir, filename);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        InputStream resourceReader = null;
        try {
            try {
                resourceReader = context.getResources().openRawResource(res);
                OutputStream dataWriter = null;
                try {
                    dataWriter = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    while (true) {
                        final int numRead = resourceReader.read(buffer);
                        if (numRead <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        dataWriter.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                    return outputFile;
                } finally {
                    if (dataWriter != null) {
                        dataWriter.flush();
                        dataWriter.close();
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (resourceReader != null) {
                    resourceReader.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send a sticker for WhatsApp you need to use mime-type is "image/webp.wasticker" while commit.
here you just need to add this

```
ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent("A waving flag", "image/webp.wasticker", mGifFile);
```